# How to check for one and only value?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have an switch with a random variable name and a array which can contain the values left, right, up and down.

For example:

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        $name='something1';
        $array=array('north', 'south', 'west');
        break;
    case 1:
        $name='something2';
        $array=array('north', 'south');
    case 2:
        $name='something3';
        $array=array('south');
}
```

How can I make a script that checks for example if the only value in the array is 'south'? In my script the output will be something3, and if I check for the value's north and south, the script would output something2?

Hope you understand me. Thanks!

Comment: One way:

`if (in_array("south", $array) && !in_array(allothervalues, $array)) {
   // South is the only value
}`

Comment: No I don't really understand... how is your question related to the `switch`?

Comment: I'd like to help but the example makes 0 sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
if((count($array) == 1) && ($array[0] == 'south')){
//code here
}
```

This will only work if the array has one element.

Ok, I think this is a pretty foolproof way of accomplishing this:

```
<?php

function checktangent($array,$tocheck){

$tocheck = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $tocheck));

if(count($tocheck) == count($array)){

    $foundall = true;

    foreach($tocheck as $value){
        if(!in_array($value, $array))
          $foundall = false;
        }
    return $foundall;
    }
else
    return false;

}


//Use like:

$array = array('north', 'south', 'west');


if(checktangent($array, 'north, south'))
    echo 'found';
    else
        echo 'not found'



?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the array can have 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 elements;-)

Comment: Hmm you said:   

How can I make a script that checks for example if the only value in the array is 'south'?    Did your requirements change?

Comment: Updated with what I think is a more helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

You can compare arrays directly in PHP. Be careful though, because this also compares the order of the values.

```
var_dump(array(1, 2) == array(1, 2)); //true
var_dump(array(1, 2) == array(2, 1)); //false
```

If you can guarantee the same order, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $directions = array('north', 'south');
    switch($directions) {
        case array('north'):
        echo 'north';
        break;

        case array('south'):
        echo 'south';
        break;

        case array('north', 'south'):
        echo 'north south';
        break;
    }
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/TCoiDw

Answer (score 1):

This should work if I understand what your looking for correctly

```
if (false == count(array_diff(array('north', 'south', 'west'), $array))) {
   echo 'something1';
} else if (false == count(array_diff(array('north', 'south'), $array))) {
   echo 'something2';
} else if (count($array) == 1 AND current($array) = 'south') {
   echo 'something3';
}
```

Comment: +1 using `array_diff`. That's the tool of choice (or `array_intersect` and the like) I would say.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution would be:

```
 array_unique($array);
 if (count($array) == 1 && in_array('south', $array))
     // Only south exists.
```